# In this C++ code, what element of the list does the iterator refer to?

Tags: c++, listiterator

Here is the code:

```
listOfFoos::iterator new_foo_it = listOfFoos.insert(listOfFoos.end(),newFoo);
```

`listOfFoos` is just that, a `std::list` of `foo` objects. Normally you would write:

```
listOfFoos::iterator new_foo_it = listOfFoos.begin();
```

I also understand that the `list.insert()` will insert a `newFoo` at the specified index, then the iterator will be created. But I don't know how the insert affects the iterator's position.

Comment: This is entirely something you could have found on your own if you had read list::insert documentation.

Comment: Retruns an iterator pointing to the first of inserted elements. You can read it here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/insert/ or here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/insert I suggest to use one of pages as a C++ reference. Both are good, use should depend on your own preferences. For asking such questions on stackoverflow you will gain negative points as this answer can be found in language reference

Comment: Thank you for the links. I did read the documentation at cplusplus.com, but I didn't interpret it correctly. I apologize for the hassle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is well documented in the manual.

> An iterator that points to the first of the newly inserted elements.

In you case `new_foo_it` after `listOfFoos.insert` of a single element, points to the last element of the list, it points `newFoo`.

Comment: [Relevant documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/insert)